# Can Android Studio JUnit Tests load properties

Tags: android-studio, junit

I've written a number of JUnit tests for an Android (Cordova) project, and up until now I've been able to run them both from the gradle command line and within Android Studio (1.2.2).

When I added some code that loads a properties file (using `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`), the code worked on an android device, and the tests still run from the gradle command line, getResourceAsStream() returns null when I run the tests within Android Studio.

Has anyone successfully been able to load properties files this way and then test them within Android Studio?

The gradle configuration for the cordova project contains this to set up the test source set:

```
subprojects {
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android.sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
        test {
            java.srcDir file('test')
            resources.srcDir file('test')
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that loading a properties file in a unit test is not best practice, but because of the nature of this project I wanted to use the properties file rather than mocking the values.